# Adding all elements to x axis, R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I can't seem to get all the Dates I need to appear on the x-axis. The dates span from 1996-2017 but I can only get R to display 2000-2015. I'm fairly new to R, and the other answers to similar questions haven't been much help.

```
breaks <- seq(1996,2017,1)
with(gamePlot, hist(gamePlot$Date, breaks, 
                         las=2,
                         col=rainbow(20),
                         xlim=c(1996,2017),
                         cex.axis=0.6,
                         xlab="Year Released",
                         main="Frequency of top rated games by year"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `plot=TRUE` to `hist`

```
with(gamePlot, hist(gamePlot$Date, breaks, 
                         las=2,
                         col=rainbow(20),
                         xlim=c(1996,2017),
                         plot=TRUE,
                         cex.axis=0.6,
                         xlab="Year Released",
                         main="Frequency of top rated games by year"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 (recommended):** Convert your dates column to a date object with `as.Date()`, then use `+ scale_x_date(date_labels = "", date_breaks = "")` on your ggplot to format the date with the arguments `date_labels` or `date_breaks`. [See this for reference.](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html)

**Option 2:** If you want to keep your date column as an integer vector (the way it is now), you can use `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = c(date1, date2, date3 ...)` and the argument `limits` to specify the breaks. You might have to convert that int column to a factor with `factor()` in order for this to work. [See this for reference.](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html)